# Triggering a build in Deis

Tags: deis

I'm trying Deis dockerfile workflow, and after pushing my changes to deis, the build failed because of a dockerhub error (HTTP code 503).

Is there a way to trigger the build again? Pushing master only gets the Everything up-to-date message, so I would have to make a change to trigger the build again?

Comment: Please take a look at https://github.com/deis/deis/issues/1774

Answer (score 0):

This behavior has been changed as of v0.15.  You can now re-push builds that failed to deploy without receiving an `Everything up-to-date` message.

For more details see the following PR: https://github.com/deis/deis/pull/2227